# Solidify modifier not working as intended

Tags: modeling, topology, solidify-modifier

I've encountered a strange solidify issue which I have been unable to correct looking through forum suggestions etc. What is happening is that I am applying a solidify modifier to my model and it's creating these extra 'lips' or flat planes where I have set my edge crease

[image: Image showing Solidify modifier creating additional model vertices]

You'll see the topology is simple, nothing I would deem complex. Removing the edge crease in the model corrects the solidify, but does not create the sharp edges I require. This is for a function part and this 'peg' on top must slide into another part.

[image: Image showing model vertices topology]

You can see from the below image, when I select display modifier in edit mode, the solidify is calculating something strange. The problem appears to be around the internal corner.

[image: Y axis view showing solidify modifier displayed in edit mode]

I have checked face orientation, merge by distance any anomalous vertices and ensured any scaling and transforms are applied.
This is for 3D printing purposes, so I would preferably require consistent thickness on the model.

Any suggestions would be most welcome, as I've spent hours trying to determine the problem.

Comment: Can you share the blend file possibly?

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your exact question, but it might accomplish the task regardless. I usually prefer to use a Bevel modifier with the profile set to 1 in combination with subdivision modifier, rather than creasing. Creasing just causes too much weirdness IMO, there's no way to debug it's behavior by looking at the geometry, it's just "doing it's own thing" and you have to accept it.

But using this workflow with the bevel width set really small, the result is almost indistinguishable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]